# How to repopulate a pre-populated android room databse, while keeping user data?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite, android-room, android-jetpack

I am trying to build an app with a dictionary, and I am currently trying to work out how to update the dictionary even after a user has installed the app and added their data. I am currently using two dictionary assets, one empty one with all the user and dictionary tables and one for the dictionary database, and using a `Migration` like this:

```
@Database(entities = [KanjiElement::class, ReadingElement::class, SenseElement::class, KanjiElementFts::class, ReadingElementFts::class, SenseElementFts::class, UserKanjiElement::class, UserReadingElement::class, UserSenseElement::class, UserKanjiElementFts::class, UserReadingElementFts::class, UserSenseElementFts::class, HistoryItem::class, Card::class, Tag::class, CardTagRelation::class, PreviouslyIncorrectCard::class], version = DictionaryDbHelper.DATABASE_VERSION, exportSchema = false)
abstract class CardMasterDatabase : RoomDatabase() {
    abstract fun cardMasterDao(): CardMasterDao

    companion object {
        var INSTANCE: CardMasterDatabase? = null
        var CONTEXT: Context? = null
        private const val FILE_NAME = "cardMasterDatabase.db"

        private val MIGRATION_1_2 = object : Migration(1, 2) {
            override fun migrate(database: SupportSQLiteDatabase) {
                if (CONTEXT != null) {
                    database.execSQL("DELETE FROM KanjiElement")
                    database.execSQL("DELETE FROM ReadingElement")
                    database.execSQL("DELETE FROM SenseElement")
                    database.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS KanjiElementFts")
                    database.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS ReadingElementFts")
                    database.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS SenseElementFts")
                    val dictionaryDbHelper = DictionaryDbHelper.getInstance(CONTEXT!!)
                    val dictionaryDb: SQLiteDatabase = dictionaryDbHelper.writableDatabase
                    database.execSQL("ATTACH DATABASE '${dictionaryDb.path}' AS dictionaryDb")
                    database.execSQL("INSERT INTO KanjiElement SELECT _ID, ENTRY_ID, KANJI_VALUE, KANJI_INFO FROM dictionaryDb.KanjiElement")
                    database.execSQL("INSERT INTO ReadingElement SELECT _ID, ENTRY_ID, READING_VALUE, KATAKANA_VALUE, FURIGANA_BOTTOM, FURIGANA_TOP, COMMONNESS, JLPT_LEVEL, READING_RELATION, READING_INFO FROM dictionaryDb.ReadingElement")
                    database.execSQL("INSERT INTO SenseElement SELECT _ID, ENTRY_ID, SENSE_ID, GLOSS, POS, FIELD, DIALECT, SENSE_INFO FROM dictionaryDb.SenseElement")
                    database.execSQL("INSERT INTO KanjiElementFts SELECT ENTRY_ID, KANJI_VALUE FROM KanjiElement")
                    database.execSQL("INSERT INTO ReadingElementFts SELECT ENTRY_ID, READING_VALUE, KATAKANA_VALUE FROM ReadingElement")
                    database.execSQL("INSERT INTO SenseElementFts SELECT ENTRY_ID, GLOSS FROM SenseElement")
                    database.execSQL("DETACH dictionaryDb")

                }
            }
        }

        fun getAppDatabase(context: Context): CardMasterDatabase? {
            CONTEXT = context
            if (INSTANCE == null) {
                INSTANCE = Room
                    .databaseBuilder(context.applicationContext, CardMasterDatabase::class.java, FILE_NAME)
                    .createFromAsset("databases/$FILE_NAME").addMigrations(MIGRATION_1_2).build()
            }
            return INSTANCE
        }
    }
}
```

Where `DictionaryDbHelper` is:

```
class DictionaryDbHelper private constructor(context: Context) : SQLiteAssetHelper(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION) {
    companion object {
        private var instance: DictionaryDbHelper? = null
        private var sharedPref: SharedPreferences? = null
        private const val DATABASE_NAME = "cardMasterDictionaryDatabase.db"
        const val DATABASE_VERSION = 2

        @Synchronized
        fun getInstance(context: Context): DictionaryDbHelper {
            if (instance == null) {
                instance = DictionaryDbHelper(context.applicationContext)
            }
            if (sharedPref == null) {
                sharedPref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context)
            }
            return instance!!
        }
    }

    init {
        setForcedUpgrade()
    }
}
```

However, this causes this error when I try to attach the second database, since the database is accessed multiple times when my app starts:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Write Ahead Logging (WAL) mode cannot be enabled or disabled while there are transactions in progress.  Finish all transactions and release all active database connections first.
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.reconfigure(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:295)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.disableWriteAheadLogging(SQLiteDatabase.java:2143)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.executeSql(SQLiteDatabase.java:1801)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.execSQL(SQLiteDatabase.java:1733)
        at androidx.sqlite.db.framework.FrameworkSQLiteDatabase.execSQL(FrameworkSQLiteDatabase.java:242)
        at com.diamonddevelopment.cardapp.data.CardMasterDatabase$Companion$MIGRATION_1_2$1.migrate(CardMasterDatabase.kt:32)
        at androidx.room.RoomOpenHelper.onUpgrade(RoomOpenHelper.java:99)
        at androidx.sqlite.db.framework.FrameworkSQLiteOpenHelper$OpenHelper.onUpgrade(FrameworkSQLiteOpenHelper.java:177)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:417)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:317)
        at androidx.sqlite.db.framework.FrameworkSQLiteOpenHelper$OpenHelper.getWritableSupportDatabase(FrameworkSQLiteOpenHelper.java:145)
        at androidx.sqlite.db.framework.FrameworkSQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(FrameworkSQLiteOpenHelper.java:106)
        at androidx.room.SQLiteCopyOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteCopyOpenHelper.java:90)
        at androidx.room.RoomDatabase.inTransaction(RoomDatabase.java:476)
        at androidx.room.RoomDatabase.assertNotSuspendingTransaction(RoomDatabase.java:281)
        at androidx.room.RoomDatabase.query(RoomDatabase.java:324)
        at androidx.room.util.DBUtil.query(DBUtil.java:83)
        at com.diamonddevelopment.cardapp.data.CardMasterDao_Impl$79.call(CardMasterDao_Impl.java:1399)
        at com.diamonddevelopment.cardapp.data.CardMasterDao_Impl$79.call(CardMasterDao_Impl.java:1396)
        at androidx.room.CoroutinesRoom$Companion$execute$2.invokeSuspend(CoroutinesRoom.kt:54)
        at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(DispatchedTask.kt:56)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:919)
        Suppressed: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Write Ahead Logging (WAL) mode cannot be enabled or disabled while there are transactions in progress.  Finish all transactions and release all active database connections first.
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.reconfigure(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:295)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.disableWriteAheadLogging(SQLiteDatabase.java:2143)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.executeSql(SQLiteDatabase.java:1801)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.execSQL(SQLiteDatabase.java:1733)
        at androidx.sqlite.db.framework.FrameworkSQLiteDatabase.execSQL(FrameworkSQLiteDatabase.java:242)
        at com.diamonddevelopment.cardapp.data.CardMasterDatabase$Companion$MIGRATION_1_2$1.migrate(CardMasterDatabase.kt:32)
        at androidx.room.RoomOpenHelper.onUpgrade(RoomOpenHelper.java:99)
        at androidx.sqlite.db.framework.FrameworkSQLiteOpenHelper$OpenHelper.onUpgrade(FrameworkSQLiteOpenHelper.java:177)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:417)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:317)
        at androidx.sqlite.db.framework.FrameworkSQLiteOpenHelper$OpenHelper.getWritableSupportDatabase(FrameworkSQLiteOpenHelper.java:145)
        at androidx.sqlite.db.framework.FrameworkSQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(FrameworkSQLiteOpenHelper.java:106)
        at androidx.room.SQLiteCopyOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteCopyOpenHelper.java:90)
2020-06-06 22:17:01.101 11440-11440/com.diamonddevelopment.cardapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at androidx.room.RoomDatabase.beginTransaction(RoomDatabase.java:352)
        at com.diamonddevelopment.cardapp.data.CardMasterDao_Impl$113.call(CardMasterDao_Impl.java:3075)
        at com.diamonddevelopment.cardapp.data.CardMasterDao_Impl$113.call(CardMasterDao_Impl.java:3072)
        at androidx.room.CoroutinesRoom$Companion$execute$2.invokeSuspend(CoroutinesRoom.kt:54)
        at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(DispatchedTask.kt:56)
        at androidx.room.TransactionExecutor$1.run(TransactionExecutor.java:45)
```

I tried to use `database.endTransaction()` before I attached the database, however, that causes this error for every time the database is accessed when my app starts:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot perform this operation because there is no current transaction.
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.throwIfNoTransaction(SQLiteSession.java:917)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.endTransaction(SQLiteSession.java:400)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.endTransaction(SQLiteDatabase.java:585)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:423)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:317)
    at androidx.sqlite.db.framework.FrameworkSQLiteOpenHelper$OpenHelper.getWritableSupportDatabase(FrameworkSQLiteOpenHelper.java:145)
    at androidx.sqlite.db.framework.FrameworkSQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(FrameworkSQLiteOpenHelper.java:106)
    at androidx.room.SQLiteCopyOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteCopyOpenHelper.java:90)
    at androidx.room.RoomDatabase.inTransaction(RoomDatabase.java:476)
    at androidx.room.RoomDatabase.assertNotSuspendingTransaction(RoomDatabase.java:281)
    at androidx.room.RoomDatabase.query(RoomDatabase.java:324)
    at androidx.room.util.DBUtil.query(DBUtil.java:83)
    at com.diamonddevelopment.cardapp.data.CardMasterDao_Impl$79.call(CardMasterDao_Impl.java:1399)
    at com.diamonddevelopment.cardapp.data.CardMasterDao_Impl$79.call(CardMasterDao_Impl.java:1396)
    at androidx.room.CoroutinesRoom$Companion$execute$2.invokeSuspend(CoroutinesRoom.kt:54)
    at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(DispatchedTask.kt:56)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:919)
    Suppressed: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot perform this operation because there is no current transaction.
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.throwIfNoTransaction(SQLiteSession.java:917)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.endTransaction(SQLiteSession.java:400)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.endTransaction(SQLiteDatabase.java:585)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:423)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:317)
    at androidx.sqlite.db.framework.FrameworkSQLiteOpenHelper$OpenHelper.getWritableSupportDatabase(FrameworkSQLiteOpenHelper.java:145)
    at androidx.sqlite.db.framework.FrameworkSQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(FrameworkSQLiteOpenHelper.java:106)
    at androidx.room.SQLiteCopyOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteCopyOpenHelper.java:90)
    at androidx.room.RoomDatabase.beginTransaction(RoomDatabase.java:352)
    at com.diamonddevelopment.cardapp.data.CardMasterDao_Impl$113.call(CardMasterDao_Impl.java:3075)
    at com.diamonddevelopment.cardapp.data.CardMasterDao_Impl$113.call(CardMasterDao_Impl.java:3072)
    at androidx.room.CoroutinesRoom$Companion$execute$2.invokeSuspend(CoroutinesRoom.kt:54)
    at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(DispatchedTask.kt:56)
    at androidx.room.TransactionExecutor$1.run(TransactionExecutor.java:45)
            ... 3 more
```

I really don't know where to go from here, so any guidance is appreciated :)

Comment: Room executes migration functions in a transaction.  Because you cannot attach to a DB within a transaction, you will need to limit the migration operations to deleting and creating tables to get the desired schema. The populating of the new tables from `dictionaryDb` can only be done after the migration is complete.  You could add a [callback](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/room/RoomDatabase.Callback) to your builder and then do the populating in `onOpen()`.  This approach may not address all the problems but I think will get you closer to a solution.

Comment: What I ended up doing was doing it manually when the database version is out of date, saved by `SharedPreferences`.